# how to keep bash from waiting for spawned windows gui program to close

Tags: windows, bash

New to bash.  And new to bash on windows and git.

When I run gitk in the git-bash shell created by msysgit, bash will effectively hang waiting for the spawned gitk to close...

Whereas cmd launches gitk and is ready and waiting for you when you switch back, without closing gitk.

How does one, in bash, get the same behavior as cmd?

Answer (score 2):

Add & to the end of the command (like "gedit &")